# microsoft word 16.0 library

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, libraries

I am working on a calculation tool on excel 2013, but to run this on my version of Excel I was forced to reference a *Microsoft Word 16.0* library.

Now as my tool is almost finished I was wondering if there is any way to compile this workbook to the normal 2013 version of Excel? Just to when a user wants to use this, they will be able to do that without referencing any external libraries?

I was checking what libraries a default Excel 2013 project has, but there is no Microsoft Word library at all, so my idea to uncheck the 16.0 library and check an earlier version can't work.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Should automatically adapt to the available reference.

Comment: What do you need the Microsoft Word type library for? Also, unless your code is invoking features (objects/types, methods) of the type library that exist in 2016 but not in 2013, then your 2013 users will be able to run the code just fine.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what for but i think it is to run macro for convert excel cells to some raport in docx, anyway when user don't have this libraries uploaded there is no chance to open the document. When i started working on this sheet i was told to upload this libraries because ithe are neccesery.

Comment: Will have to know why that library is needed, you can work around some references by using late binding, it takes some awareness and will force the code to be different instances.  You can also try and add the GUID reference for the user when the workbook opens, that is another story.

Comment: If your code requires Microsoft Word, it won't run on a machine that doesn't have Microsoft Word - late-bound or not.

Comment: Also I don't think "upload" means what you think it does ;-)